# Self dual posets product

Tags: combinatorics, examples-counterexamples, order-theory

> Let $P,Q$ be partially ordered sets such that $P\times Q$ is self dual.
> Self dual means $(P\times Q)^*=P\times Q$ where $P^*$ is the dual of $P$.
> Does that mean $P,Q$ are self dual?

My professor hinted that the answer is negative, that in particular there exist non self dual $P,Q: P\times Q$ is self dual. Why is that true? Is there a counterexample of two such sets?

Comment: Do $(P\times Q)^*$ and $P\times Q$ have to be equal, or can they simply be isomorphic?

Comment: Just isomorphic, it suffices for the Hasse diagram of $P\times Q$ to be symmetric that is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the partial orders $\langle\Bbb N,\le\rangle$ and $\langle\Bbb N,\ge\rangle$. Neither is self-dual — each is the dual of the other, in fact — but their product is self-dual.

Comment: Nice! Can this be generalized like considering in general $P\times P^*$?

Comment: @idocomb: Yes, it should give you an example for any $P$ that isn’t self-dual.